# Concatenate array keys with the previous array element

Tags: php

I'm trying to remove duplicate timestamps from a log of mine, whereby the array values from the duplicate rows have to be concatenated into the previous array row's values..

So far I've managed to remove the duplicate timestamps. But I'm having trouble concatenating the array values into the previous values, assuming that the datestamp is not present in that specific array.

Please help me contenate the values into the previous array?

the log file follows the following format :

```
20160420084726:-
20160420085418:[111783178, 111557953, 111646835, 111413356, 111412662, 105618372, 111413557]
20160420085418:[111413432, 111633904, 111783198, 111792767, 111557948, 111413225, 111413281]
20160420085418:[111413432, 111633904, 111783198, 111792767, 111557948, 111413225, 111413281]
20160420085522:[111344871, 111394583, 111295547, 111379566, 111352520]
20160420090022:[111344871, 111394583, 111295547, 111379566, 111352520]
```

How do I remove the duplicate timestamps while preserving the values into the previous line, and while keeping the last contenated values /n newline character.

```
<?php
$filename = "datesandids.log";
$lines = explode("\n", file_get_contents($filename));
print_r($lines);

$count = count($lines);
for ($i = 0;$i < $count;$i++) {
    $lineattr = explode(":", $lines[$i]);
    echo $lines[$i];
}

foreach ($lines as $linevar => $row) {
    $line = explode(":", $linevar);
    print_r($lines);
}

$handle = fopen("$filename", "r");
$datevar = array();
while ($line = fgets($handle)) {
    $line = trim($line);
    $data = explode(":", $line);
    $datevar[] = $data;
}

var_dump($datevar);

$found = array();
function concatArray($array, $keys, $glue = " ") {
    $last = null;
    foreach ($array as $key => & $value) {
        if (in_array($key, $keys)) {
            if ($last === null) {
                $last = $key;
                continue;
            }
            $array[$last] .= $glue . $value;
            unset($array[$key]);
        }
    }
    return $array;
}

foreach ($datevar as $i => $x) {
    if (in_array($x[0], $found)) {
        $datevar[$i][0] = '';
        $date = array(
            $datevar
        );
        print_r(concatArray($date, array(
            0,
            1
        )));
    }
    else {
        $found[] = $x[0];
    }
}

print_r($datevar);
foreach ($datevar as $key => $value) {
    $datevar[$key] = preg_replace("/\[/", "", $value);
}

foreach ($datevar as $key => $value) {
    $datevar[$key] = preg_replace("/\]/", "", $value);
}
print_r($datevar);
?>
```

I'm trying to produce the following array information :

```
Array(
    [0] => Array(
        [0] => 20160420084726
        [1] => -
    )

    [1] => Array(
        [0] => 20160420085418
        [1] => 111783178, 111557953, 111646835, 111413356, 111412662, 105618372, 111413557, 111413432, 111633904, 111783198, 111792767, 111557948, 111413225, 111413281, 111413432, 111633904, 111783198, 111792767, 111557948, 111413225, 111413281
    )

    [2] => Array(
        [0] => 20160420085522
        [1] => 111344871, 111394583, 111295547, 111379566, 111352520
    )

    [3] => Array(
        [0] => 20160420090022
        [1] => 111344871, 111394583, 111295547, 111379566, 111352520
    )
)
```

I'm actually getting :

```
Array(
    [0] => Array(
        [0] => 20160420084726
        [1] => -
    )

    [1] => Array(
        [0] => 20160420085418
        [1] => 111783178, 111557953, 111646835, 111413356, 111412662, 105618372, 111413557
    )

    [2] => Array(
        [0] => 
        [1] => 111413432, 111633904, 111783198, 111792767, 111557948, 111413225, 111413281
    )

    [3] => Array(
        [0] => 
        [1] => 111413432, 111633904, 111783198, 111792767, 111557948, 111413225, 111413281
    )

    [4] => Array(
        [0] => 20160420085522
        [1] => 111344871, 111394583, 111295547, 111379566, 111352520
    )

    [5] => Array(
        [0] => 20160420090022
        [1] => 111344871, 111394583, 111295547, 111379566, 111352520
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try an approach like this:

```
<?php
$filename = "datesandids.log";
$rows = explode(PHP_EOL, file_get_contents($filename));
$result = Array();

foreach($rows as $key => $row){
    $keyval = explode(':', $row);

    $keyval[1] = str_replace('[', '', $keyval[1]);
    $keyval[1] = str_replace(']', '', $keyval[1]);
    $keyval[1] = explode(', ', trim($keyval[1]));

    if(!isset($result[$keyval[0]])){
        $result[$keyval[0]] = $keyval[1];
    }else{
        $result[$keyval[0]] = array_merge($result[$keyval[0]], $keyval[1]);
    }
}

var_dump($result);
```

[PHP documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) says:

> An array in PHP is actually an ordered map. A map is a type that
>   associates values to keys. This type is optimized for several
>   different uses; it can be treated as an array, list (vector), hash
>   table (an implementation of a map), dictionary, collection, stack,
>   queue, and probably more. As array values can be other arrays, trees
>   and multidimensional arrays are also possible.

In this way you don't have to worry about duplicates so much

Moreover i suggest you to use the [PHP_EOL Constant](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php) to explode your file so you don't have troubles with other systems

The output will be like that:

```
array(4){ 
    [20160420084726]=> array(1) { 
        [0]=> string(1) "-" 
    } 

    [20160420085418]=> array(21) { 
        [0]=> string(9) "111783178" 
        .
        .
        [20]=> string(9) "111413281" 
    } 

    [20160420085522]=> array(5) { 
        [0]=> string(9) "111344871" 
        .
        .
        [4]=> string(9) "111352520" 
    } 

    [20160420090022]=> array(5) { 
        [0]=> string(9) "111344871"
        .
        .
        [4]=> string(9) "111352520" 
    } 
}
```